# How can I merge my Tumblr blogs?

Tags: import, merge, export, tumblr

Title pretty much says it all. Blogs are under the same account. [Asked this question on Quora](http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-merge-my-Tumblr-blogs) with little response.

I'm looking for perhaps a web app, which automates the process. If there isn't anything already out there, I'm ready to build my own web app using [Tumblr's API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post describing for detailed explanation of moving data from one Tumblr to another http://vinylanswer.tumblr.com/post/42009904333/how-to-turn-your-secondary-tumblr-blog-into-your

Comment: Very cool! But, truth be told, I don't like the idea of using Wordpress as a bridge... it's a hack. So, I'm gearing up in developing a web app to address this issue. I'm merely gathering information to see if anyone has already developed something along these lines. I do appreciate your answer though!